# How to create an event with relationship to participant?

Tags: civievent, relationships, online-registration

We would like to run kids club every month. During Registration we use main participant profile as Child's details. But we also need to have contact details of parents in case of emergency.

I was thinking to create a custom data/profile with relationship but I was not able to find any option to do that.

What is the best way to capture the details of parent so a report can be easily retrieved with child & parent details?

Thanks

Comment: If you mention your CMS you will get other answers. Pradeep mentions webform for drupal, caldera forms may also give what is required for WP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using webform for drupal or caldera for wordpress. The CiviCRM webform/caldera provides ability to add multiple contacts and relationship (and also events) on a single form.

Comment: Can you clarify that webform is for Drupal, and Caldera may do it for WP?

Comment: Thanks Peter, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing to do would be to have a custom data set on the childs record.

Parent/ next of kin name, phone, email etc

Event profiles won't really let you add a related contact